# Click DIV doesn't make a “real” click operation in IE

Tags: testing, internet-explorer-8, watin

Browser: Internet Explorer 8 with compatibility view turned on (the tested application was written for IE7). I have a div element, which looks like a checkbox in the browser. When I manually click it the checkbox ticks itself. Here is how this looks like: http://img593.imageshack.us/g/divunchecked.jpg/ When clicked manually the div element also changes it's class attribute from "x-grid3-check-col" to "x-grid3-check-col-on". When I run a Watin test and make a Div.Click() operation the element doesn't check itself. Html of that element:

```
<DIV class=x-grid3-check-col onclick=booleanInterviewColumnRender_OnClick(this);>&nbsp;</DIV>
```

I have tried to:
 - click 2 of the div's parents (it is placed in 2 other divs)
 - `Div.MouseDown(); 
Div.MouseUp();`
 - `Div.Firevent("onclick");` 
 - `NameValueCollection eventProperties = new NameValueCollection(); 
eventProperties.Add("button", "0"); 
Div.FireEvent("onmousedown", eventProperties); //left mouse click` 
 - `Div.SetAttributeValue("class", "x-grid3-check-col-on"); 
    Div.Refresh();`

without luck.
Any ideas how to workaround this would be great.

Answer (score 2):

The last workaround is to run directly the javascript call.

if you put an id on your div element: `elementID`

then you call

```
div.Document.Eval("document.getElementById(\"elementID\").fireEvent(\"onclick\")");
```

And it will call the onclick call back you put in your attribute (you can first try in the console to be sure that the javascript call your callback).

However, I think that the WatiN mehod .FireEvent on the Element does the same thing, so I don't understand why you need this workaround.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot add an id to the element, I'm just testing - the application is developed by a totally different team

Comment: you always have a way to get an element in javascript, if you don't have any JS framework (like jQuery) on your page, you can come back to the old fashion style: http://tinyurl.com/6baunvy. Or you can dynamically inject jQuery in your page :)

Comment: Ah the element faces some JS error when trying to select it. Tried all workarounds but with no success. Question closed